# How to exclude 0 in this method?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a code:

```
public function getMinPrice() {
        return array_reduce($this->getProduktLinks()->toArray(), function($lowest, $link) {
            return min($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
        });
    }
```

And I'd like to exclude records where `price = 0` from it. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add a reproducible dataset so we understand what kind of data the function is using.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getMinPrice() {
    return array_reduce($this->getProduktLinks()->toArray(), function($lowest, $link) {
        if($link->getPrice() != 0 && $lowest != 0){
            return min($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: $lowest will never be 0 if getPrice is never 0 too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on one line, but you are risking un-readability, so I would suggest something like:

```
public function getMinPrice() {
    return array_reduce($this->getProduktLinks()->toArray(), function($lowest, $link) {
        $min = min($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
        return $min ?: max($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
    });
}
```

The logic is simple, if the lowest is false(i.e. 0), it will return the other. If both are 0 however, you can add some other logic if you need it. It would look something like this:

```
public function getMinPrice() {
    return array_reduce($this->getProduktLinks()->toArray(), function($lowest, $link) {
        $min = min($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
        return ($min ?: max($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice())) ?: "some other value";
    });
}
```